# what is the correct to affect every string test in Yup with Formik

Tags: reactjs, string, formik, yup

(This is all being done through Formik)

I compile a Yup Schema through imports from multiple files:

A typical schema:

```
export const PersonalSchema = {
  name: Yup
    .string('Name must be a string')
    .required('Name is required')
    .min(3,'Name must be at least 3 characters')
    .max(250,'Name must be less than 250 characters'),
  altname: Yup
    .string('Alternative name must be a string')
    .max(250,'Alternative name must be less than 250 characters'),
}
```

And some master file including two schema,each from different files:

```
const MasterSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    ...PersonalSchema,
    ...WorkSchema
})
```

Some of the schema use `.when`.

I have been tasked with ensuring that no string contains html tags. In reality, there are some 30 or so string fields.

Thus far I have used:

```
Yup.addMethod(Yup.string, 'noHTML', function(args) {
  return this.matches(/^(?!(?:.|[\n\r])*<[a-z][a-z0-9]*\b[^>]*>)/i, args)
})

export const ExtraSchema = {
  bio: Yup
    .string()
    .max(4000,'Must be less than 4000 characters')
    .noHTML("HTML tags are not accepted"),
}
```

This is becoming painful.

(yes I know the expression isn't perfect)

I am looking for a method to either affect `.string` in such a way as to disallow HTML or to extend it. The latter is preferable just in case one field might allow it one day.